# Using Bash "test" operator on Python output?

Tags: python, linux, bash, command-line

I have been tasked with using a bash-based tooling platform that makes use of the bash "test" operator. For example, it can assert if a new file is created with this simple command:

```
test -f /root/mynewfile
```

My test will evaluate the output of a Python3 script, particularly the output of any `print()` calls. The user is expected to create a Python file called `task1.py`, and within it call `print()` on an expression that will output `0.12`.

To check if this was successful I tried to put this command in my bash script:

```
test $(python3 task1.py) = \"0.12\"
```

However it does not seem to be returning anything, and trying to pipe this output into a file will indicate nothing was outputted.

Any bash gurus know how to fix this?

Comment: It does return a status, which is accessible through `$?`.

Comment: `test` doesn't assert anything.  Try `test $(python3 task1.py) == 0.12 && echo yes || echo no`.

Comment: @TimRoberts this is helpful thank you. Looks like I'm overthinking a few things and been in Python and Java land for awhile.